# SonarQube scanner: use non-default Java

Tags: sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-scan

I have a box running SonarQube scanner. The default JDK is 7.

I need to run `sonar-runner` using JDK 8 but I would like to keep the default JDK at 7.

I tried changing `JAVA_HOME` before running `sonar-runner` but had no luck. I also couldn't find any properties that can change that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting *JAVA_HOME* should work (see *sonar-scanner* [source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli/blob/master/src/main/assembly/bin/sonar-scanner#L88) if you're curious).

It's behaving well for me with SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1. Default on Java 7:

```
nico@deb-nico:~$ sonar-scanner 
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/nico/sq_playground/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
INFO: Java 1.7.0_101 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
```

Forcing to Java 8:

```
nico@deb-nico:~$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
nico@deb-nico:~$ sonar-scanner 
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/nico/sq_playground/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
INFO: Java 1.8.0_91 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
```

Looking good. Note that the [SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwiththeSonarQubeScanner) has a built-in option to let you choose which JDK the scanner should use.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I was using `sonar-runner` rather than `sonar-scanner`.