# Jenkins: Loading plugin Jenkins SonarQube Plugin v2.5 (sonar) failed / Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

In our Jenkins running on Windows server and with JRE 7 we installed the newest version of the SonarQube plugin: 2.5.

Hint: We need JRE 7 for running Jenkins because of another plugin which is pretty old and which doesn't work with Java 8.

Then, while Jenkins startup the following warning was logged:

```
WARNING: Loading plugin Jenkins SonarQube Plugin v2.5 (sonar) failed perhaps due to plugin dependency issues
java.io.IOException: Unable to load hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPlugin from sonar
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:514)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:517)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:1026)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

After Jenkins startup the SonarQube plugin was NOT visible in 'Plugin Manager' / 'Installed'.

After we downgraded the plugin to version 2.4.4 everything worked properly again.

Does it mean that SonarQube plugin v2.5 requires Jenkins running on JRE 8?

Or can this problem be solved in another way?

UPDATE: I tried to fix the problem by setting JAVA_HOME to a Java 8 folder. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube scanner: use non-default Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105537/sonarqube-scanner-use-non-default-java)

Answer (score 2):

Updating the Jenkins.xml and the java executable to \Java\jre1.8.0_112\bin\java fixed my issue.  Im running SonarQube 6.1, Jenkins 2.27 with the Sonar Plugin 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Indeed SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins requires JDK 8 since version 1.5.

I'm not sure how Jenkins select the JDK it will run with (could rely on `JAVA_HOME` or use the one in the PATH) but at least on my Linux box I can force it to use a specific JDK installation using `JENKINS_JAVA_CMD` (can be set in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` or probably as environment variable).

Comment: In jenkins.xml file we set <executable>%BASE%\jre_7u25x64\bin\java</executable>. 
Thus, Jenkins starts using given JRE 7 version. So I suppose that the SonarQube plugin in Jenkins is also executed using JRE 7. Does the plugin support it?